# click on a div that contains an onclick with watir gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

I have this div:

```
<div id="loadDIV" class="containerLogo" onclick="ventanaSecundaria('/bienvenido.php',800,600); "></div>
```

How I can run the onclick event inside the div with watir gem?

class = containerLogo displays a logo on the browser.  When you click on that logo, you run the script "ventanaSecundaria", and it opens another window with the contents of bienvenido.php.  Tried it with mechanize and nokogiri gems to no avail, and they recommended trying watir gem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're question is pretty brief, so if you edit it to answer these questions, I think you'll get some more help: What happens when you click on the `div` with this code? What do you want to have happen? Why are you trying to accomplish with Watir?

Comment: As @Kevin says, welcome! Stack Overflow expects you to show that you've put effort into solving the question you're asking. You do that by showing code you've written, plus any errors, or an explanation why it doesn't do what you want. If you haven't written code, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`fire_event`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) method.  These are the examples from the watir-webdriver rdoc:

```
browser.a(:id => "foo").fire_event :click
browser.a(:id => "foo").fire_event "mousemove"
browser.a(:id => "foo").fire_event "onmouseover"
```

From the supplied HTML, this would be the watir-webdriver code:

```
browser.div(:id => "loadDIV").fire_event :click
```

One thing to note: the rdoc says "that you may omit “on” from event name."

And--if you are using watir-classic--here's the link to the [`fire_event`](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) method.